# How to delete elements from to do list?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object-oriented-analysis

I apologize if this is a bit confusing to read, this is my first post.
Please consider the following code:

HTML:

```
...
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="to-do-input" placeholder="Add new task..">
            <button id="add-to-do" type="button">Add ToDo</button>
        </form>
        <div id="to-do-container">
        </div>
...
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  var addButton = document.getElementById("add-to-do");
  toDoArray = [];

            addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                let nHTML = '';
                let todoValue = document.getElementById("to-do-input").value;
                toDoArray.push(todoValue);
                
                toDoArray.forEach( function(item) {
                    //READ BELOW
                    //<!--set each array item's id to it's own string value minus white spaces
                    var itemId = item.replace(' ','');
                    item.setAttribute("id", itemId); //console: "item.setAttribute is not a function"
                    //-->

                    nHTML += '<li>' + item + '  <button id="delete">Remove</button> </li>';
                });
                document.getElementById("to-do-container").innerHTML = '<ul>' + nHTML + '</ul>';
                document.getElementById("to-do-input").value = '';
        });
```

PROBLEM:
The plan is to set each array item's id value to its own string value minus all spaces via .replace(), but the console is saying:

```
app.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: item.setAttribute is not a function
    at app.js:17:26
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:14:27
```

I tried to also type item.setAttribute("id", `${itemId}`), but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Your array contains strings, not html elements as you are storing the elements value in the array, push the element into the array and change the code after to replace on item.value, then setAttribute will be defined

Answer (score 0):

Fixed JavaScript code:

```
const addButton = document.getElementById('add-to-do');
const input = document.getElementById('to-do-input');
const toDoContainer = document.getElementById('to-do-container');
const toDoArray = [];

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toDoArray.push(input.value);

  toDoContainer.innerHTML = `<ul>${toDoArray
    .map(
      (todo) =>
        `<li id='${todo.replace(
          ' ',
          '',
        )}'>${todo}<button id="delete">Remove</button> </li>`,
    )
    .join('')}</ul>`;

  input.value = '';
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I copy and pasted your code, but now the console is saying
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>"

Comment: now it's saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')"

Comment: ah my bad, have tinkered with it and updated answer.

Comment: No worries, feel free to ask any questions about the code.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Javascript code:

```
var addButton = document.getElementById("add-to-do");
    toDoArray = [];

    addButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let nHTML = '';
        let todoValue = document.getElementById("to-do-input").value;
        toDoArray.push(todoValue);

        toDoArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
            //READ BELOW
            //<!--set each array item's id to it's own string value minus white spaces
            var itemId = item.replace(' ', '');
            // item.setAttribute("id", itemId); //console: "item.setAttribute is not a function"
            //--> //This line has been replaced

            nHTML += `<li id='${itemId}'>` + item + `  <button id="delete" onclick="dltFun(${index},${itemId})">Remove</button> </li>`; //This line has been replaced
        });
        document.getElementById("to-do-container").innerHTML = '<ul>' + nHTML + '</ul>';
        document.getElementById("to-do-input").value = '';
    });

    function dltFun(index, itemId) {
        let element = document.getElementById(itemId)
        element.remove()
        toDoArray.splice(index, 1)
    }
```